# Internal server error 500 when calling a post API

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, post, swagger

I'm testing an api when I send a post request the server responds with `Code: 500 Error: Internal Server Error` Get requests work perfectly fine. 
here is the link to API. Its a Swagger UI
https://loan-management-solution20191108021340.azurewebsites.net/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the API receives your request but in its process ocurrs a not handled exception. If you have acces to this api you could check your Log (if you have) or report it to the admin. Either way, the errors occurs on server side.